# Eclipse: hide orange arrows in lines related to AOP aspect (JAVA)

Tags: java, eclipse

In my Eclipse oxygen I have a Java Project with Spring and Aspect (to do automatic logging/traces around some methods).

Suddenly, today in each method affected by the Aspect it shows a orange arrow with a tooltip saying:

"advised by bla.bla.bla(JoinPoint)"

or

"2 Spring AOP marker at this line"

I believe this is recently since I installed a Spring Boot dashboard to launch Spring aplications easily.Or perphaps I touched an option in eclipse (not on purpose)

I would like to hide those arrows, two days ago they didn´t appear.

I have taken a look at eclipse preferences, or "Marker" or AOP options, but i dont see the option.

Any idea, please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Window,Preferences, General, Editor, Text Editors, Annotations.

Suddenlye at the top of the list, now there are several

Advice

AJDTx2

Aspect Advice

AspectJ Advice

Disable the Vertical rules and overview ruler